# How can I access a Netty Handler method from outside of the normal flow

Tags: netty

I am trying to integrate Netty (version 3.6.1.final) into our current system so I can replace the current NIO code.

Currently we have a messaging Bus where events are queued for other listeners to process and put another event back on the bus for further processing.

In my Netty business logic handler's  messageReceived() method, I will be adding an Input Request to the bus.   One thing I will be passing is the data from the Netty event message.

I figure that I should pass the ChannelHandlerContext in this InputEvent along with the data/message received.  So that eventually when the OutputEvent is processed, It can use the ChannelHandlerContext that was originally passed around to send the processed data back to the requesting client on the correct Netty Channel.

So how can the Output task that is processing the OutputEvent tie back into Netty?

Do I issue some call using the ChannelHandlerContext I have using as input the processed data.  I don't want to tie up the Output task.

Code snippet from Netty handler.

```
public void messageReceived(
        ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {

    byte[] message = (byte[])e.getMessage();

    try {
            data.add(message);
        }
    catch( IOException ioe )
        {
            logger.error(ioe);
        }

    InputEvent ie = new InputEvent( ctx, this, data.getBuffer() );

    try {
              bus.enqueue(ie);
    }
    catch( Exception ex )
   {
      logger.error(ex);
   }
```

Code snippet from Output processor.

```
public void run() {


    // note that the OutputEvent (event) is available here.  This is not a Netty event.
    ChannelHandlerContext ctx = event.getHandlerContext();
    ClientChannel handler = event.getHandler();

    // I need to send the data in event.getBuffer() back.

// Now what do I do here???


…
…
…

}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You just would call:

```
InputEvent event = ...
ChannelHandlerContext ctx = ....
ctx.write(event.getBuffer());
```

Or:

```
InputEvent event = ...
Channel channel = ....
channel.write(event.getBuffer());
```

Comment: As simple as that.  Great!  Netty will help us immensely with our NIO issues.  Thank you Norman.

Comment: I wanted to ask this.  When I write the data out to the ctx or channel, will that basically hand it off to the channel and I won't have to wait in the Output task for the write cycle to complete?  By write cycle, I meant for the data to reach the client.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes it will not wait... If you need to wait you can call await*() on the returned ChannelFuture, but don't do this in an IO thread..

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.  I don't want to wait.  I just want to put the letter in the mail box and go on my way. :)  Thanks again Norman.

Comment: I figured it would be best to convert the ByteBuffer that is returned by event.getBuffer() to a ChannelBuffer.  So I used:  ChannelBuffer cb = ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer(event.getBuffer());  And then did: ctx.getChannel().write(cb);

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Make a new connection.
    ChannelFuture connectFuture =
        bootstrap.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));

    // Wait until the connection is made successfully.
    Channel channel = connectFuture.awaitUninterruptibly().getChannel();

    // Get the handler instance to retrieve the answer.
    FactorialClientHandler handler =
        (FactorialClientHandler) channel.getPipeline().getLast();//get("your handler name")
```